# No OpenCL platforms found

Tags: opencl, gpu

I am running an XFX RX 580 gpu and OpenCL is not detecting it.

When I type:

```
eth --list-devices
```

I get:

```
cpp-ethereum, a C++ Ethereum client
[OPENCL]:No OpenCL platforms found
[OPENCL]:
Listing OpenCL devices.
FORMAT: [deviceID] deviceName
```

but when I type:

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
```

The GPU is clearly recognized:

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:67df] (rev e7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device [1682:c580]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
    Memory at 2fe0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 2ff0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at f7040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: Don't confuse OpenCL and OpenGL. The message tells you OpenCL is not detected.

Comment: Typo has been corrected. Issue still stands.

Comment: ``lspci`` say you have a piece of hardware, it says nothing about drivers. Do you have any OpenCL runtime installed ?

Comment: Which AMD driver do you have? do you have an OpenCL ICD in your system? (usually in /etc/OpenCL/vendors) ? If not you probably don't have the right library or packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Install amdgpu driver or AMDAPPSDK